# EC2 error: cannot create temp file for here-document: Read-only file system

Tags: amazon-ec2, filesystems, ubuntu-14.04

Looks like my Ubuntu 14.04 EC2 made the fs read-only.

```
cd /var/  (pressing tab for autocomplete)
```

cannot create temp file for here-document: Read-only file system

But I have plenty of free space and memory is not full either:

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-48-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

  System information as of Wed Feb  3 14:40:58 UTC 2016

  System load:  0.0                Processes:           126
  Usage of /:   14.9% of 11.67GB   Users logged in:     0
  Memory usage: 19%                IP address for eth0: 172.31.15.38
  Swap usage:   0%
```

df -hi:

```
/dev/xvda1       768K   85K  684K   12% /
none             251K     2  251K    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev             249K   387  249K    1% /dev
tmpfs            251K   309  250K    1% /run
none             251K     1  251K    1% /run/lock
none             251K     1  251K    1% /run/shm
none             251K     2  251K    1% /run/user
```

free:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       2048484    1199420     849064       6248     180300     635596
-/+ buffers/cache:     383524    1664960
```

du -sch /tmp*

```
9.9M    /tmp
9.9M    total
```

What's the solution here? How can I fix the fs without losing my data?

Should I run:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
```

or should I reboot?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am facing same issue, did you got a solution?

Comment: Hello, did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have btrfs filesystems? If so, when there´s not enough space for more snapshots, the OS changes their properties to read-only (including /tmp). For me, the solution was to delete snapshots and disable the snapper.

Use the following commands:

- `snapper list`  #shows a numbered list of snapshots
- `snapper delete nmbr` #deletes snapshot number nmbr (retry after reboot if doesn't work at first)

Also, disable automatic snapshots by deleting corresponding files under `/etc/cron.hourly`, `/etc/cron.daily`, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue and fixed the same as below:
There was a bad arguments given by someone for /etc/fstab

Wrong Entry in "/etc/fstab":

```
[ec2-user@XXXXXXXXXXX ~]$ cat /etc/fstab
#
UUID=XXXXXX     /           xfs    defaults,noation  1 1
```

and Corrected entry is as below:

```
[ec2-user@XXXXXXXXXXX ~]$ cat /etc/fstab
#
UUID=XXXXXX     /           xfs    defaults,noatime  1 1
```

Answer (score 0):

**Maybe you don't have write permission to the /tmp/ directory.**

Check permission and it should be look like

```
ls -ld /tmp  
drwxrwxrwt 10 root root 4096 Jun  5 11:32 /tmp
```

You can fix the permissions followed by

```
chmod a+rwxt /tmp
```